# $f:S^{m}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. F radial expansion of f. Show that F is diferential on 0 iff f is a restriction of a linear application

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> $f:S^{m}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. F radial expansion of f. Show that F is diferential on 0 iff f is a restriction of a linear application.

Define $F:\mathbb{R}^{m+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ $F(0) = 0; F(x) = |x|f\left(\frac{x}{|x|}\right)$ if $x\not=0$

$(\Leftarrow)$ Let f be a restriction of a linear application
Let $F'(0)$ s.t. 
$$F'(0)v = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{F(tv)-F(0)}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{|tv|f(\frac{tv}{|tv|})-0}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\frac{|tv|}{|tv|}tf(v)}{t} = f(v)$$
$\therefore$ if $F(v) = F(0)+F'(0)v+r(v)$ then

$r(v) = F(v)-F(0)-F'(0)v=|v|f(\frac{v}{|v|})-f(v)$ and

$\lim_{v\to 0}\frac{r(v)}{|v|} = \lim_{v\to 0}\frac{|v|f(\frac{v}{|v|})-f(v)}{|v|} = \lim_{v\to 0}\frac{f(v)-f(v)}{|v|}=0 \therefore$ F is diferentiable on 0.

Now I have a problem with the other way.

$(\Rightarrow) F(v) = F(0)+F'(0)v+r(v)$ s.t. $\lim_{v\to 0}\frac{r(v)}{|v|}=0$.

$F(v) = |v|f\left(\frac{v}{|v|}\right)=F'(0)v+r(v)\implies f\left(\frac{v}{|v|}\right) =\frac{F'(0)v+r(v)}{|v|}$.

My intention was to manage to get $f(v) = F'(0)$ hence proving f must be a linear application restrict to $S^{m}$, but I don't know what to do with that last expression.

Comment: Write $\boldsymbol{v}=t\boldsymbol{e}$ for a unitary vector $\boldsymbol{e}$, then $\lim_{t\to 0}r(t\boldsymbol{e})/t=0$, hence $f(\boldsymbol{e})=F'(0)\boldsymbol{e}+\lim_{t\to 0}r(t\boldsymbol{e})/t=F'(0)\boldsymbol{e}$.

Comment: "$f:S^{m}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. F radial expansion of f. Show that F is diferential on 0 iff f is a restriction of a linear application." I do not understand what you are saying, Please define all terms.